# Is it okay to contact an employee at a company you're considering to work in?

Tags: contracts

I'm considering working at a company that I've already interviewed and received a verbal offer. The opportunity is a contract that might convert to a full time.

Before I accept the offer I wanted to get a general impression on the experience working there as a consultant and the longevity of the contract. Do you think it is okay to contact an employee that currently works there but worked as a consultant in the past in the same position? The way I can contact them is via LinkedIn.

Comment: I might follow up with somebody with whom I had interviewed or had an existing social connection, but it'd be awkward to contact anybody else.

Comment: Have you checked glassdoor?

Answer (score 11):

If you have no existing social connection to them, they are likely to consider this gratuitously annoying. If you have a single specific question that can be answered in under a minute, you may get an answer. If the person you contact is involved in recruiting you may get an answer. Otherwise you'll be just one more piece of annoying junk mail at best.

Interesting idea, probably won't hurt you, but I think you're going to be disappointed.

Comment: Agreed, definitely would not hurt to try.

Answer (score 2):

The point of the interview process is to ask the relevant questions to get an idea of what it will be like to work there.

If you are contacting someone you don't know to ask them if they like working there, how can that relate to you as you may like completely different working environments?

If you had worked with someone in the past, then it's fine. But to contact a complete stranger, I wouldn't do that

Answer (score -1):

I think you should avoid making the contact. It just seems risky to me. I think it might make you appear to be an indecisive, needy person.